# Paypal login android sdk Single Sign On

Tags: android, paypal, authentication

I am trying to implement  the Paypal social login using the Android SDK, but server-side we don’t seem to be able to retrieve the user’s account information from the token returned by Paypal return to the client.  This way we cannot login/register the user into the database.

The token received from paypal sdk seem be ok but server can't get user account info.
Using this curl `curl -v https://api.paypal.com/v1/identity/openidconnect/userinfo/?schema=openid \
    -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer access token from paypal sdk"`
I receive this error

> Bearer error_description="Invalid Access Token",correlation_id="my_id",error="invalid_token",information_link="https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#errors",realm="UserInfoService"

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research, i found the proble.
Paypal mobile sdk doesn't allow "Single Sign On" for now.

> Log In with PayPal is not currently available for Mobile SDK apps

More informations about this can be found here [Paypal doc](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/admin/manage-apps/#provide-information-for-a-log-in-with-paypal-app)